# Getting the ip address of eth0 interface in java only return IPv6 address and not IPv4

Tags: java, ipv4, inetaddress, network-interface

I wrote the following code to get the IPv4 address of the eth0 interface I am using on a machine. However the code only finds `fe80:x:x:x:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx` which is not returned since I am looking for the IPv4 address.

Here is the code.

```
    interfaceName = "eth0";
    NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByName(interfaceName);
    Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddress = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
    InetAddress currentAddress;
    currentAddress = inetAddress.nextElement();
    while(inetAddress.hasMoreElements())
    {
        System.out.println(currentAddress);
        if(currentAddress instanceof Inet4Address && !currentAddress.isLoopbackAddress())
        {
            ip = currentAddress.toString();
            break;
        }
        currentAddress = inetAddress.nextElement();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was messing with the logic where it gets the next element. I had the `inetAddress` next element being gotten before the `while` compare was ran. Thus making there be no more elements.

The following code has then fixed the logic

```
    interfaceName = "eth0";
    NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByName(interfaceName);
    Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddress = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
    InetAddress currentAddress;
    currentAddress = inetAddress.nextElement();
    while(inetAddress.hasMoreElements())
    {
        currentAddress = inetAddress.nextElement();
        if(currentAddress instanceof Inet4Address && !currentAddress.isLoopbackAddress())
        {
            ip = currentAddress.toString();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems to me that to be semantically correct you'd want to remove the first call to `intetAddress.nextElement()` - the one _before_ the while loop, since you will always be throwing the first element away as it is currently written!

Comment: currentAddress.toString() returns "/192.168.1.13". so perhaps use this instead: currentAddress.getHostAddress() which returns "192.168.1.13"